# What's the proper way to check page similarity?

Tags: duplicate-content, content

The following are two sample web pages I have created:

- `example.com/index1.htm`
- `example.com/index2.htm`

I have deliberately used the same HTML markup and same bloated in-line stylesheet code in both. The only thing different between the two pages is the actual user readable text.

I first tested the two pages with [studiokraft](http://www.studiokraft.com/index.php/action/page-similarity-checker) and it reports that the pages are 91.64% similar to each other. This makes me believe everything is factored in their similarity algorithm (text, HTML, and CSS).

I ran the exact same pages unaltered through this [webconfs](http://www.webconfs.com/similar-page-checker.php) and it reports 22% similarity.

I'm trying to avoid high similarity percentage so that Google doesn't think I have duplicate content on my site, and now I don't know what tool to believe.

My question is how do I evaluate page similarity myself? do I factor the HTML and CSS along with the text or just only the text?

Comment: Sorry but there is already various questions and answers on Pro Webmasters regarding if markup/template is considered duplicate, worded in various ways. In terms of testing your content your doing everything right, web apps that do not ignore markup you need to copy just the text, no markup, or use ones that automatically ignore it.

Comment: That post you refer me to was last updated probably 4 years ago. Is that information still accurate today? Google has changed a number of things since then such as their maps and product forums.

Comment: Age of questions is irrelevant on all Stacks due to the fact that old questions can be edited and new answers can be created. It is not valid to create new questions because you can't find a satisfactory answer. We also have methods of bumping questions through legitimate editing and improving the questions or answers, or running a bounty to gain even more attraction.